# ios dropbox image thumbnail in tableview without using image cache

Tags: ios, xcode, dropbox

I want to put dropbox thumbnails in my tableview without using the dropbox SDK, because I don't want to use image cache or something.

If thumbnail doesn't exist I put in a default image, but when a thumbnail exists I don't know how to gain it from dropbox and put in my tableview:

```
NSString *fileIconName;
if ([[cellDescriptor objectForKey:@"fileThumbnailExists"]boolValue]==YES)
{

}
else {
fileIconName = [cellDescriptor objectForKey:@"fileIcon"];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:fileIconName];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you do not want to use the Sync API for iOS? You could still use the Dropbox [iOS SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/files#ios). Using the iOS SDK just set up a DBRestClient object and then call the [/thumbnails endpoint](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api#thumbnails). I am not entirely sure I understand the question, but I hope this helps.